# responder status = 200 con Laravel

Tags: laravel, https

Luego de recibir datos de una URL en forma de json, debo responder con status [acknowledgment] (ACK 200) para que no siga enviando la notificación.
 esta es la función :

```
public function tryNotification(Request $request) {


    //recibimos la notificacion y la procesamos
    $request = json_decode($request);
    //guardamos la notificacion en la BD
    $saveNotification = new Notifications();
    $saveNotification->seller_id = $request->user_id;
    $saveNotification->resource = $request->resource;
    $saveNotification->topic = $request->topic;
    $saveNotification->received = $request->received;
    $saveNotification->save();
    //envia mensaje de RECIBIDO a Meli
    //aqui necesito la ayuda de como enviar respuesta de recibido al servidor
    //retorna datos guardados en la BD
    return response()->json($saveNotification);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale, Para colocar un código en la cabecera de tu respuesta, eso se coloca como segundo parametro de la repuesta de JSON.

```
//response()->json(object,code_status)

return response()->json(Array,911);
```

[La documentación no lo muestra](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#json-responses), pero se puede ([yo lo uso](https://github.com/QueHayPaHacerCtg/QueHayPaHacerCtg_Backend/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/CategoriasController.php))

Answer (score 0):

```
Siguiendo tu código puedes usarlo al pie de la letra solo agregando un segundo parámetro a tu línea del return

public function tryNotification(Request $request) {
    //recibimos la notificacion y la procesamos
    $request = json_decode($request);
    //guardamos la notificacion en la BD
    $saveNotification = new Notifications();
    $saveNotification->seller_id = $request->user_id;
    $saveNotification->resource = $request->resource;
    $saveNotification->topic = $request->topic;
    $saveNotification->received = $request->received;
    $saveNotification->save();
    //envia mensaje de RECIBIDO a Meli
    //aqui necesito la ayuda de como enviar respuesta de recibido al servidor
    //retorna datos guardados en la BD
    //Puedes pasar el estado que deseas en este caso use el 201 para ejemplificar el empleo del segundo parametro
    return response()->json($saveNotification, 201);

}
```